# In Cypress, how to pass optional parameter in Step Implementation

Tags: javascript, typescript, cucumber, cypress, gherkin

In below scenario the "model" parameter is optional because it is only needed for one bank. And for other bank we don't need this model parameter. But I want to make one single "When" syntax implementation to make it resuable for all of the bank

```
Scenario Outline : Merchant creates an account in abc bank.
   Given I am a merchant
   When  I create a "<type>" "<bank>" with "<model>"
   Then I should receive a response
   And I should received expected details
   Examples:
      |type | bank | model|
      |abc  | xyz  | Test |
```

Step Implementation file:

```
    When('I create a {string} {string} with {string}', (type, bank, model) => {

     })
```

Comment: Please elaborate your issue properly, As the current question is not clear or unable to understand the actual issue & sample shared here!

Answer (score 1):

Write a separate scenario for each bank. Don't put your parameters in the feature file push them down into the step definition. Differentiate between your two types of bank with a name.

In general don't try and be efficient by writing big complex steps that cover lots of use cases. Instead be clear and simple by writing lots of small simple steps.

You don't need to use scenario outlines and you don't need to use examples. Generally they make Cukes harder to read and less precise.

From your question you might end up with

```
Given I am a merchant
When  I create an abc type bank with model
  
Given I am a merchant
When I create a xyz type bank
```

Which is much simpler.